# how to open file of extension pcxm and get details about them

Tags: file-format

I have a file with extension `.pcxm`. It is new for me I haven't heard about this file format.

Can anybody guide me how to view/open such file and also explain what type this file is and for what purpose it used?

I have Googled but I haven't got solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pcx stands for  PointCloudXplore (PCX) and in this case 'M' stands for matlab file pcxm files are where all the specifications regarding matlab functions are saved

you can also look here for more details

http://books.google.co.in/books?id=1R5uIP8hcgYC&pg=PA272&lpg=PA272&dq=pcxm+files+in+matlab&source=bl&ots=QtcsyAo0lX&sig=uTPqu1wCmeKMVInfd7ipmIVNnQQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=D8F8UpHeHsiKrQeS2oG4DQ&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=pcxm%20files%20in%20matlab&f=false

and

http://vis.lbl.gov/Vignettes/pcxMatlab-2012/